# Iterating through a 3d array

Tags: c, arrays

I've been trying to use for loops to try to iterate and print out the array. When i try to print out i get these random numbers and i dont know where they are coming from.

```
 const char segments[10][3][3] =
        {
                {{' ', '_', ' '}, {'|', ' ', '|'}, {'|', "_", '|'}}, // segments for 0
                {{' ', ' ', ' '}, {' ', '|', ' '}, {' ', "|", ' '}}, // segments for 1
                {{' ', '_', ' '}, {' ', '_', '|'}, {'|', "_", ' '}}, // segments for 2
                {{' ', '_', ' '}, {' ', '_', '|'}, {' ', "_", '|'}}, // segments for 3
                {{' ', ' ', ' '}, {'|', '_', '|'}, {' ', " ", '|'}}, // segments for 4
                {{' ', '_', ' '}, {'|', '_', ' '}, {' ', "_", '|'}}, // segments for 5
                {{' ', '_', ' '}, {'|', '_', ' '}, {'|', "_", '|'}}, // segments for 6
                {{' ', '_', ' '}, {' ', ' ', '|'}, {' ', " ", '|'}}, // segments for 7
                {{' ', '_', ' '}, {'|', '_', '|'}, {'|', "_", '|'}}, // segments for 8
                {{' ', '_', ' '}, {'|', '_', '|'}, {' ', "_", '|'}}, // segments for 9
        };


for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(segments); k++){
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(segments); j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(segments); ++i) {
            printf("%c", segments[k][j][i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

When i run the code it gives me an output of something like this:

|_| �| _ |_  �| _ |_ |�| _   | �| _ |_||�| _ |*| �|�#�z���Z��ث�|*| �| _ |_  �| _ |_ |�| _   | �| _ |_||�| _ |_| �|�#�z���Z��ث� �| _ |_  �| _ |_ |�| _   | �| _ |_||�| _ |_| �|�#�z���Z��ث� _ |_  �| _ |_ |�| _   | �| _ |_||�| _ |*| �|�#�z���Z��ث�|*  �| _ |_ |�| _   | �| _ |_||�| _ |_| �|�#�z���Z��ث� �| _ |_ |�| _   | �| _ |_||�| _ |_| �|�#�z���Z��ث� _ |_ |�| _   | �| _ |_||�| _ |*| �|�#�z���Z��ث�|* |�| _   | �| _ |_||�| _ |_| �|�#�z���Z��ث�|�| _   | �| _ |_||�| _ |_| �|�#�z���Z��ث� _   | �| _ |_||�| _ |_| �|�#�z���Z��ث�  | �| _ |_||�| _ |_| �|�#�z���Z��ث� �| _ |_||�| _ |_| �|�#�z���Z��ث�@ _ |_||�| _ |*| �|�#�z���Z��ث�@�Z|*||�| _ |_| �|�#�z���Z��ث�@�Z|�| _ |_| �|�#�z���Z��ث�@�Z _ |*| �|�#�z���Z��ث�@�Zұ4|*| �|�#�z���Z��ث�@�Zұ4Y �|

Comment: Put some simple elements in a test array, such as 'a','b','c' to confirm your iteration code. You will find your limit test in your loops is questionable.

Comment: Hint: Review use of `sizeof(segments)`

Comment: You code will not compile due to ***double-quotes*** around, e.g. `"_"`.

Comment: Now would be good time to find out where the compiler warnings go in your IDE!

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(segments)` gets the size of the entire array in memory, not the length of any of its axes.

As per the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c), you can still use `sizeof`, you just need to use it on different parts of the array: to get the length of each axis, divide its total length by the length of one of its elements.

```
some_type_t const array[I][J][K] = ARRAY_INITIALIZER;

// array size over size of subarray
size_t const i_max = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

// subarray size over size of sub-sub-array
size_t const j_max = sizeof(array[0]) /
                     sizeof(array[0][0]);

// sub-sub-array size over size of one element
size_t const k_max = sizeof(array[0][0]) /
                     sizeof(array[0][0][0]);

for (size_t i = 0; i < i_max; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < j_max; ++j) {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < k_max; ++k) {
            // do something with array[i][j][k]
        }
    }
}
```

From the same answer, you can use the following macro to generate those expressions automatically.

> ```
> #define NELEMS(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))
>
> int a[17];
> size_t n = NELEMS(a);
> ```

## Why it works

You might expect `sizeof(array[0])` to fail on a zero-length array, which might make you hesitate to use it. But don't worry—this should work for any (non-variable-length) array.

Page 80 of [this draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) of the C standard describes how the `sizeof` operator works:

If `sizeof` is given anything besides a variable-length array, it doesn't evaluate it—the compiler can find out how big the operand is and it just uses that value.

So, after I defined `array` in the example above, the compiler knows that any element of `array` has type "length-*J* array of length-*K* array of `some_type_t`" (in other words, `some_type_t[J][K]`). It also knows the values of *J* and *K*, because they need to be inline constants, so it can determine how big any element of the array is.

As a result, it doesn't matter what index you use to find the size of the element, as long as it is an integer. `sizeof(array[0])` will work just fine with an empty array, as would `sizeof(array[-1])` or `sizeof(array[124124])` (though you should always use 0 to avoid confusing people).

As a matter of fact, the standard draft even uses it as an example:

> 6. EXAMPLE 2 Another use of the `sizeof` operator is to compute the number of elements in an array:
>
>    ```
>    sizeof array / sizeof array[0]
>    ```

And if the standard suggests it, it's probably a pretty good way to do it.

Comment: You forgot the double quotes.